# Use of log-linear analysis with percentage data

Tags: repeated-measures, independence, log-linear

Although my question sounds like I have data suitable for log-linear analysis, I may not. I have a large number of students (about 1000) of two levels who solved a test of 8 different types of problems (which have specific features and categorized at two different levels).

Thus I have three types of independent variables: `type of problem`, some other `features of problems`, and `student level`.  I want to see if there are main and interaction effects along these dimensions.

Since the dependent variable is dichotomous, I need a nonparametric test.  Also it should be a repeated design, since same students answered 8 different questions.  So the first question is: **Is there such a test?**

What I did was calculate the percentage of correct solutions for each case and ran a log-linear analysis, which I am not quite sure about (as it violates the independence assumption).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to run a logistic regression model that uses correct answer (yes or no) to the question as the response and then the other independent variables can but controlled for in teh model as main effects and interaction terms.  You could always run 8 separate logistic regression models (i.e., one for each question) or you could put a 8-level covariate into the model that is basically an indicator function for which question you are considering.